# Using barcode scanner to read barcode in forms 10g

Tags: forms, oracle, oracle10g, barcode

I want to use barcode to read instead of using input from keyboard. I use Key Enter trigger and passing null against it but it did't fire. Any solution.....

Answer (score 0):

I Googled for it and found [this article](http://www.erpgreat.com/oracle-database/how-to-read-bar-codes-in-oracle-forms.htm).  The pertinent line is

> "In order to cause the key-next-item to execute you will need to ensure
>   the bar code reader sends a TAB key sequence at the end of each scan
>   so that the key-next-item trigger will fire."

I don't know whether that will solve your problem but the solution will probably be something along those lines: configuration of the reader.